# How to calculate element-wise mean of a list of matrices while excluding NaNs

Tags: r

Lets say I have list of matrices. How would you calculate another matrix whose elements are the element-wise mean of the list of matrices, accounting for and excluding NaNs? Suppose we have a list of matrices:
)

```
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   1    4    7
[2,]   2    5    8
[3,]   3    6    9

> B
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   2    5    8
[2,]  NaN  NaN  NaN
[3,]   4    7   10

> C
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   3    3    6
[2,]   2    3    7
[3,]  NaN  NaN  NaN

> my.list <- list(A, B, C)
```

My desired output is:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   2    4    7
[2,]   2    4   7.5
[3,]  3.5  6.5  9.5
```

As you can see, I wish to calculate the element-wise mean of the list, but excluding the NaN values of the matrices in the list. So for instance element [1,1] of the output is (1 + 2 + 3) / 3 = 2, but element [3,1] of the output is (3 + 4) / 2 = 3.5, since we excluded the NaN in that position in matrix B. Any idea how to calculate this?

Answer (score 1):

Convert to `array` and then use `apply` to loop over and get the `mean`

```
 apply(simplify2array(my.list), c(1, 2), FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

-ouptut

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  2.0  4.0  7.0
[2,]  2.0  4.0  7.5
[3,]  3.5  6.5  9.5
```

---

or may loop over one dimension and use `rowMeans`

```
apply(simplify2array(my.list), 2, rowMeans, na.rm = TRUE)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  2.0  4.0  7.0
[2,]  2.0  4.0  7.5
[3,]  3.5  6.5  9.5
```

---

Or another option is

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(data.table)
 map_dfr(my.list, as.data.frame, .id = 'grp') %>% 
   group_by(grp = rowid(grp)) %>% 
   summarise(across(everything(), mean, na.rm = TRUE), 
       .groups = 'drop') %>%
   select(-grp)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     V1    V2    V3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   2     4     7  
2   2     4     7.5
3   3.5   6.5   9.5
```

#### data

```
my.list <- list(structure(1:9, .Dim = c(3L, 3L)), structure(c(2, NaN, 4, 
5, NaN, 7, 8, NaN, 10), .Dim = c(3L, 3L)), structure(c(3, 2, 
NaN, 3, 3, NaN, 6, 7, NaN), .Dim = c(3L, 3L)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  # input prepare
  A= matrix(1:9,nrow=3,ncol=3)
  B = matrix(2:10,nrow=3,ncol=3)
  B[2,] = NaN
  C =matrix(c(3,2,NaN,3,3,NaN,6,7,NaN),nrow=3,ncol=3)

  # flatten every matrix as a column of rowMeans big matrix
  # so rowMeans do element-wise process
  mat.as.vec.list = lapply(list(A,B,C), as.vector)
  bind.by.col= do.call(cbind, mat.as.vec.list)

  
  mean.by.row = rowMeans(bind.by.col, na.rm = T)

  #convert back to matrix
  dim(mean.by.row) = dim(A)
  mean.by.row

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  2.0  4.0  7.0
[2,]  2.0  4.0  7.5
[3,]  3.5  6.5  9.5
```